# React Modal with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, storybook, react-modal

I am tying to simply hide and show Modal using react-modal but I get error please help! I'm assuming the problem is that when the storybook is running, there is not document / body specified for typescript with react fragment and storybook.

Is there a workaround here? Should I just avoid using react-modal and find another library to do my popup menu in the header?

*Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClickOpen is not defined*

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactModal from 'react-modal';

ReactModal.setAppElement('#root');

export interface BFModalProps {
    className ?: string,
    isOpen?: boolean,
    isClose?: boolean,
    title?: string,
    handleClickOpen?:() => any,
onClick?:() => (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void,
    handleClickClose?:() => any,
    disabled?: boolean,
    showCtaButton?: boolean,
    children?: any,
    showModal?: boolean
}


const BFModal: React.FC<BFModalProps> = ({
    showCtaButton = true,
    isOpen = false,
     isClose = true,
}) => {
    const [open, showModal] = React.useState(true);
    const [close, hideModal] = React.useState(false);

    // const showModal = false;

    const handleClickOpen = () => {

        debugger;
       showModal(true);
        isOpen = true;
        debugger
        hideModal(false);
        isClose = false;
        debugger

        console.log('handleClickOpem is clicked');

    };



    const handleClickClose = () => {
        debugger;

        showModal(false);
        debugger;

        isOpen = false;
        console.log('handleClickClose is clicked');
        debugger;

    };



    return (
        <div>
            {
                showCtaButton &&
                <button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Trigger Modal</button>
            }

            <ReactModal
                isOpen={false}
                contentLabel="Inline Styles Modal Example"
                aria={{
                labelledby: "heading",
                describedby: "full_description"
            }}
                style={{
                    overlay: {
                        backgroundColor: 'papayawhip'
                    },
                    content: {
                        color: 'lightsteelblue'
                    }
                }}
            >
                <div>Modal text!</div>
                <button onClick ={handleClickClose} >Close Modal</button>
            </ReactModal>
        </div>
    );
}
export default BFModal;
```

Comment: Did you try replace to  inline function without declaration of it, directly in event

Comment: I tried declaring it in props as `onClick?:() => (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void,` still did not work.

Comment: Did you try setAppElement  in useEffect, also can you try post the code as live example.

Comment: You can extend your example here: https://codepen.io/claydiffrient/pen/KNxgav